# Can't load Flask config from parent directory

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to follow the docs here on using configuration files: http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/configuration.html#the-simple-case

I want to use what they call "the simple case" but I want to load the `config.py` from the parent directory. My project tree looks like this:

```
~/Learning/test $ tree
.
├── app
│   └── __init__.py
└── config.py
```

This is my `app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
```

This is my `config.py`:

```
DEBUG = True
```

This is the error I get when I try to run my project:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    app.config.from_object('config')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/config.py", line 163, in from_object
    obj = import_string(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 443, in import_string
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 418, in import_string
    __import__(import_name)
werkzeug.utils.ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'config'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'config' not found.

Original exception:

ImportError: No module named config
```

I want to keep the `config.py` in another directory from the Flask app files. How can I make Flask load the `config.py` from the parent directory here?

Answer (score 11):

You can't load it from there because as the error message says:

> ```
> - missing __init__.py in a package;
> - package or module path not included in sys.path;
> ```

It's not part of a package that is importable.  This may have worked locally because you were running `python` in your project root so the current directory was implicitly added to the path.  Do not rely on this behavior.  Do not manually change `sys.path`.

Instead, Flask's [`Config`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Config) has alternate ways to load the config: from a path in an environment variable

```bash
export FLASK_CONFIG="/path/to/config.py"
```

```
app.config.from_envvar('FLASK_CONFIG')
```

or from a file relative to the [instance folder](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/#instance-folders)

```
app/
    __init__.py
instance/
    config.py
```

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```